# What is the best way in Excel formula to parse out this string?

Tags: string, excel, parsing

I have a column of data and each cell has something like:

```
   Last First (Id)
```

such as :

```
  Thompson Joe (ABC12323)
```

and i want to parse out the:

```
  ABC12323
```

NOTE: in some rare cases I see there are two ids listed like this:

```
  Thompson Joe (ABC12323) (DEF1123432)
```

and in this case i would want to parse out the second one

```
   DEF1123432
```

what is the easiest way to do this in an excel formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this nasty beast:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

The `LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")` will find the number of occurrences of space " ". The `Find(Substitute)` will give you the length of the cell up to that last occurrence of a space. Then it just uses `Right()` to pick that last section out.

The cool thing is that this will return the last word in a sentence, regardless of it's length.

Updated: Added a couple substitutes to get rid of the parantheses:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),"(",""), ")", "")
```

Comment: it looks like this includes the "(" and ")" in the result, is there a way to NOT include those?

Comment: Doh! Editting that now

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),")",""),"(",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```